# Why my server is up and down successively?

Tags: web-server, hosting, web-hosting

Our server has just been hacked few days ago, we made a complete backup of it, but, from that time, we get erros while trying to access our websites hosted on it : some times, everything works perfectly, and then when we refresh the page, we get an error message :

Internal server error

Where could that come from ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to completely rebuild the server.  See http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency.

Comment: Read the logs, they'll tell you why it's erroring.

Comment: Ask the admin :-)

Comment: Please tell me you made a complete backup *before* you were hacked, because otherwise your backup cannot be trusted.

Comment: Yes sure, the backuo seemed to be all right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the logs. The answer is there:

- [Apache Logs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html)
- Lighthttp logs: `/var/log/lighttpd`
- [Some nginx logs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule)
- Linux Logs:

  - `/var/log/message`
  - `/var/log/auth.log`
  - `/var/log/kern.log`
  - `/var/log/secure`
  - `/var/log/yum.log`
- MySQL logs: `/var/log/mysqld.log`